# user code-push on iOS platform , prompt code-push is undefined, and can not call apis of code-push service

Tags: ios, react-native, code-push

I need use code-push service in react-native on iOS platform. Version is 1.17.3-beta.

Local already deployed code-push service. then run the command line to import code-push plug-in.

As shown below.

```
npm install --save react-native-code-push

react-native link react-native-code-push
```

Loading code-push module in js.

```
import codePush from 'react-native-code-push'
```

There is a problem. prompt `codePush` is undefined. And I can not call apis for example `checkForUpdate()` `sync()`.

```
componentDidMount(){
      AppState.addEventListener("change", (newState) => {
        newState === "active" && codePush.sync();
      });
    },
```

The documents of code-push can be found in node_modules directory,but why not be identified ?

Can any one help please ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure codePush is undefined?

Try this:

```
...
const codePushOptions = { checkFrequency: codePush.CheckFrequency.ON_APP_RESUME };
App = codePush(codePushOptions)(App);

AppRegistry.registerComponent('MyApp', () => App);
```